# MySQL - how not to return rows matching

Tags: mysql

Sorry, title is probably very ambiguous but can't think way of shortening what I want...

Basically have 2 tables one containing a unique ID and other main fields, a secondary feature table. Every unique ID has 1 or more row in feature table with a 2 char code. e.g...

```
uid | feature
----|--------
001 | AA
002 | AA
002 | AB
003 | AB
```

When finding something with a feature(s) this is easy and uses a left join to main table and a where feature in ('AA','AC') etc.. however the problem is when trying to exclude something which has specific features.

Using above example if I wanted to show only uid which do not have the feature of AB (e.g. only 001) I cant just use a "where feature != 'AB'" as this will still return 002 (due to the AA feature).

Is there anyway of doing what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a not in with subselect

```
select uid from my_table 
where uid not in  (select uid from my_table where  feature = 'A')
```